# The task "Good consistency" from Yandex.Contest. Java8 / C#

Tags: c#

```
A sequence of n points in three-dimensional space is given. 
It is necessary to find such an even permutation of its indices 
that after its application the sequence becomes good.
```

Here is a link to the solution of this problem:

```
https://studwork.org/away?href=https%3A%2F%2Fhabr.com%2Fru%2Fcompany%2Fyandex%2Fblog%2F340784%2F%23%3A~%3Atext%3D%25D0%25BF%25D0%25B0%25D0%25BC%25D1%258F%25D1%2582%25D0%25B8%253A%2520256%2520%25D0%259C%25D0%2591-%2C%25D0%25A0%25D0%25B5%25D1%2588%25D0%25B5%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B8%25D0%25B5%2C-%25D0%2597%25D0%25B0%25D0%25B4%25D0%25B0%25D1%2587%25D1%2583%2520%25D0%25BC%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B6%25D0%25BD%25D0%25BE%2520%25D1%2580%25D0%25B5%25D1%2588%25D0%25B8%25D1%2582%25D1%258C
```

I wrote a program, but the answer is incorrect or the program is written incorrectly. Here is the program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace Journey_CSharp_5
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<List<int>> points;
            int n;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("input.txt"))
            {
                n = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
                points = new List<List<int>>(n);

                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    String coords = sr.ReadLine();
                    string[] tokenscoord = coords?.Split(' ');
                    if (tokenscoord != null) points.Add(new List<int>
                                                    {
                                                    int.Parse(tokenscoord[0]),
                                                    int.Parse(tokenscoord[1]),
                                                    int.Parse(tokenscoord[2])
                                                    });
                }


                bool ok = Check(points);
                int[] perm = { 0, 0, 0 };

                Random rand = new Random();
                while (!ok)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) perm[j] = rand.Next() % n;
                    if (perm[0] == perm[1] || perm[0] == perm[2] || perm[1] == perm[2]) continue;
                    var points_copy = points;
                    var tmp = points_copy[perm[0]];
                    points_copy[perm[0]] = points_copy[perm[1]];
                    points_copy[perm[1]] = points_copy[perm[2]];
                    points_copy[perm[2]] = tmp;
                    ok = Check(points_copy);
                }

                List<int> ans = new List<int>();
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) ans.Add(i);
                int tmp1 = ans[perm[0]];
                ans[perm[0]] = ans[perm[1]];
                ans[perm[1]] = ans[perm[2]];
                ans[perm[2]] = tmp1;

                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("output.txt"))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) sw.Write(ans[i] + 1);
                }
            }
        }


        private static long Vect(long xp, long yp, long xt, long yt)
        {
            return xp * yt - yp * xt;
        }


        private static bool CheckOrder(int i, int j, List<List<int>> points)
        {
            int[] signs = { 0, 0, 0 };
            for (var k = 0; k < points.Count; k++)
            {
                int prv = (k - 1 + points.Count) % points.Count;
                int cur = k;
                int nxt = (k + 1) % points.Count;

                long vres = Vect(
                points[cur][(int)i] - points[prv][(int)i], 
                points[cur][(int)j] - points[prv][(int)j],
                points[nxt][(int)i] - points[prv][(int)i], 
                points[nxt][(int)j] - points[prv][(int)j]);

                switch (Math.Sign(vres))
                {
                    case -1:
                        signs[0] += 1;
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        signs[1] += 1;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        signs[2] += 1;
                        break;
                }
            }
            return (signs[0] != 0 && signs[2] != 0) || (signs[1] != 0);
        }


        private static bool Check(List<List<int>> points)
        {
            List<Tuple<int, int>> ids = new List<Tuple<int, int>>
                    {
                    new Tuple<int, int>(0, 1),
                    new Tuple<int, int>(1, 2),
                    new Tuple<int, int>(0, 2)
                    };

            bool ok = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) ok &= CheckOrder(ids[i].Item1, ids[i].Item2, points);
            return ok;
        }
    }
}
```

Verdict:

```
wrong-answer
```

I also rewrote this program in C# and get the compilation log:

```
stdout:
Compilation succeeded - 1 warning(s)


stderr:
warning CS8001: SDK path could not be resolved
```

Although only Mono C# 5.2.0 can be selected on this site.

Please tell me what is wrong with my program?

Comment: Please choose _either_ C# or Java.

Comment: It doesn't matter to me in what language, but preferably in C#. But there may be problems with the Mono SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to remove the directive using

```
System.Linq;
```